# Orientate the centers of a Master Pyraminx (Pyraminx 4x4)

Tags: rubiks-cube, algorithm, mechanical-puzzles, twisty-puzzles

I have a very strange state on my 4x4 Pyraminx. The green side is solved and the other sides are almost solved, the problem is, on these 3 remaining sides the centers are not solved. The state looks like this (sorry if it's a bit blurry):
[image: Strange Pyraminx State]

Is there any algorithm that I could use to solve this weird state? When answering keep in mind that I'm new to the Master Pyraminx and don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the parity that occurs on a 4 by 4 pyraminx. It does indeed have an algorithm, so I will be outlining that below.

1. Put the solved center on the left side. In your case it would be the green side on the left.
2. With the green side on the left, do the following algorithm:

- R U R' U R U R' U

  You may need to do that algorithm again, to fix the centers. It should also be mentioned that the moves above are 3 layer movements, so when it says R move the 3 right layers clockwise, and vice versa. Be warned that by using the algorithm the top corner and surrounding edges will be misplaced. That is normal.

3. Then, use this algorithm to solve the misplacement of the top corner and edges:

- R U R' U R U R' U (where the R moves are 3 layer moves like the first algorithm and the U are 2 layer movements.) Do this algorithm again if you need to, and you should be able to solve parity.

Comment: If you want I can make an animation of what I described.

Comment: I'd like you to make an animation If you can, since I find the letter algorithms hard to understand.

Comment: For the letter algorithms, there are many sites online to understand the notation of rubix cubing. But for animations sake, I will make one.

Comment: Additionally, don't forget to contribute more to the site! Upvote questions and answers you like, and don't forget to read the tour of the site!

Comment: Sorry, I would've upvoted but can't yet since my reputation here is still below 15

Comment: That's completely fine. Now to work on how to animate this...

Comment: Welp, failed the animation. Hopefully you will understand what you mean, and if not, I will post pictures instead.@MissingUser